# Events being cancelled automatically

Tags: civievent, iats

Good Morning Everyone,
We have a client running CivCRM 5.36.1 on Drupal 7.  All extensions are up to date.  Since the middle of April we have noticed some participants are receiving notices that there event registration has been canceled.  In all cases these participants were sent the link for payment by the event coordinator using the "Will Pay Online" option.  Payment completes fine. There are no errors in payment processor logs or any of the Civi logs.  The record of the cancellation shows up in the activity list and the log database.  The timing is usually (all cases but one) immediately upon completion of payment. In all cases but the last one, even though the cancellation message was sent and recorded in the database, no cancellation actually occurred.

In the last case, the participant did receive the cancellation notice when payment was received as everyone else without the registration actually being canceled.  Then, 4 days later, they received a cancellation notice but this time the event registration was actually canceled. Again, the activity log shows the cancellation with the "Added by" being the participant.

We continue to dig into this but have found nothing to indicate why it is happening.  It is not happening to all users.  It happens to a few users registered to the same event in the same way.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Which payment processor are you using?  What extensions relate to payments or events?  Is CiviRules involved?

Comment: Hi @Aidan. We are using the iAts payment processor.  The only other extension that affects payments is the "Contribution Cancel Actions" extension.  We did modify that extension slightly to place an entry into dblog whenever it was executed.  It was not executed for any of the canceled contributions after that code was put in place and there have been a few.

Comment: CiviRules are not in use.